# Group by with left join

Tags: postgresql

I need to to sum (quantity and amount) for each product sold in in the table "account_invoice_line"

```
SELECT seller.name
ipartner.name AS invoice  
brand.name AS brand, pt.name AS product,  
SUM(ail.quantity) AS quantity, SUM(ail.price_subtotal) as amount  
FROM account_invoice_line ail    
LEFT JOIN account_invoice i ON ail.invoice_id = i.id    
LEFT JOIN res_partner AS ipartner on ipartner.id = i.partner_id  
LEFT JOIN res_users u ON u.id = i.user_id  
LEFT JOIN res_partner AS seller ON seller.id = u.partner_id  
LEFT JOIN product_product pp ON pp.id = ail.product_id  
LEFT JOIN product_template pt ON pt.id = pp.product_tmpl_id   
LEFT JOIN brand ON brand.id = pp.brand_id  
GROUP BY seller.name, invoice, brand, pt.name
ORDER BY seller.name, invoice, brand, pc.name, pt.name
```

Unfortunately, I get this king of result:
 -
Seller, Invoice, Brand, Product, Quantity, Amount
...
Seller1, Customer1, Brand1, Product1, 5, 4.70
Seller1, Customer1, Brand1, Product1, 10, 9.30
...
I was expecting for this (summed quantity and amount for the same product):
Seller1, Customer1, Brand1, Product1, 15, 14.0

Comment: You have pc.name in your order by but not in your GROUP BY or SELECT? I don't see it in your FROM either. What is that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need left joins for all of the tables?
Having account_invoice_line and then add LEFT JOIN, could make that one of the fields is NULL on the other tables, and that might be a reason why you see 2 records instead of one (let's say partner id is NULL in one of them).

Comment: As lines are the same (except for quantity and amount), I think I have values for each field:

Comment: Give it a try, I don't get why to use left join if you don't need it, query seems ok to me, maybe it's just the data and a INNER JOIN might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If u just group by one column name only (for example: brand), do u still get same result?

Comment: If I write this only:
    GROUP BY pt.name,  
  
I get error message:  
    column "seller.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function